# Determine the field lines to the vector field $F(x, y) = (x^3 y, x y^3)$

Tags: vector-fields

I can't find a proper way to determine the field lines to a vector field! For example, if I have the field $F(x, y) = (x^3 y, x y^3)$, how can I find its field lines? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field lines for a vector field $F$ are the set of lines that have $F$ as their tangent. These satisfy $$F_x dy=F_y dx$$

Now insert $F_x=x^3y$ and $F_y=xy^3$, separate and integrate. If you're still having troubles with it after this, or are seeking a proof of the relation I gave, let me know in the comments below.

Comment: Okay thanks! So after we integrated the functions we got $x^2y^2(x-y) = C$. Are these the field lines for said vector field?

Comment: @Nard Yes, view them as [contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) which vary when you vary C. Try drawing them for different C to get a feel for the flow of the field.

Comment: @Nard Glad to help! This is going to sound awfully self-interested, but since you're new to the site I'd just tell you that in addition to "accepting" an answer you can also up/down-vote posts - it's the arrows just above the "accept"-tick. Just to let you know, you of course do not have to upvote my answer! Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I tried to upvote your answer but since I'm not at +15 reputation my votes wont publicly change the score.

Comment: @Nard Oh yes, that, I had forgotten about that, sorry about the unnecessary information then! :)